# Ubuntu - Execute multiple php files via command line

Tags: linux, php, command-line-interface

How do I execute multiple php files via command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call them one after each other:

```
a.php; b.php; c.php
```

Comment: Just a quick note: With `;`, all subsequent commands will execute when one failed. with "&&", further commands will only execute when the previous finished without error.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you don't want to type out all the names:

```
ls *.php | xargs -tn1 php
```

This being Unix, there are many (many) other ways to do this too.

Comment: Your name is pretty slick, but I might have added "Some *Totally Random* Guy".